# How do I uninstall Apache on Windows 8, when there is no uninstaller?

Tags: windows, apache-http-server, php, uninstall

I have Apache 2.4 and PHP installed, and I want to remove them in order to install WAMP.
I can't find the Apache or PHP uninstallers, not inside any of the folders, and it's not even in "add/remove programs".

Does anybody know what can be done in order to remove both without leaving garbage?

Comment: How were they installed in the first place?

Comment: I am not aware that Apache uses anything outside its installation folder.  But I personally would just install both again, then uninstall it, if you really want to run the uninstall executable.

Comment: Michael Kjörling: I wish i'd remember :(
Ramhound: I'm not insisting on the uninstall executable :) I just want to know how to remove them completely...

Answer (score 1):

To uninstall the Apache service run (from elevated command-line, Run as admin) `httpd -k uninstall`.

Then you can delete the Program Files\ folders of Apache and PHP.